# Laravel/Lumen bind interface on middleware based on user input

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm quite new to this so pls bare with me. :)

I have 2 implementations of an interface, let's just name them `BankService1` and `BankService2` and both of them adheres to `DisbursementInterface`.

Typically if I only need one implementation, i would just bind the interface and the implementation in `bootstrap/app.php` and inject the interface to the constructor of the controller. However, I want to dynamically bind the implementation based on user input kind of like this:

```php
//if remittance is true, use bank 1 else bank 2
$disbursementService = ($request['remittance'] ? 'BankService1' : 'BankService2');

$this->app->bind('My\Namespace\DisbursementInterface', "My\Namespace\\{$disbursementService}");
```

I think the middleware is the best place to do like this since i need the `$request` object. However i'm having a hard time binding the implementations because like what i said, i'm still quite new at this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All I actually need is to create a Service Container! I don't actually need it to be in the middleware at all.

```php
class DisbursementServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(DisbursementInterface::class, function($app) {
            if ($this->app->request->remittance) {
                return new BankService1();
            }

            return new BankService2();
        });
    }
}
```

after that, I registered my service container in `bootstrap/app.php` and now it works! I can now switch between implementations based on user input :)